# Why Hex code not Uploading in Proteus?

Tags: microcontroller, programming, proteus

I am unable to upload hex code in proteus and get a pop up saying

I did this :-

- Picked up a PIC16 MCU
- added up a HEX file of the code i created (It is a simple blink code, code is working fine)

When i clicked on play, it poped up a window shown below 
 :-
[image]

**PS: Everything else (AVRs,ARMs,MSP etc are working perfectly but none of the PIC116 MCUs are running**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Add to your question the minimum steps required to reproduce this error.

Comment: I have done that, please have a look

Comment: Do what it says, re-install your program again. If you are doing something illegal, like cracking the keys, then you are doing it wrong, and you should not illegally use these programs.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar experiences with HEX files in Proteus. Depend on the compiler you are using, the HEX file can content blanks or additional text at the end of the HEX code. In some case it works in ISIS if you delete this additional text (like date, or similar) or blanks the HEX file.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you try to run a program that is for an older or newer version of Windows than you have. Check the tool documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, actually  it seems like PIC16 series don't run on Windows, not sure may be.Everything else is working perfectly fine